# Groovy - Может ли метод выдавать два результата?

Tags: groovy

Например, возможно ли в Groovy следующее:

```
def dva (U) {   
   X = U + 1; Y = U + 3
   return X; return Y
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете вернуть их внутри списка, и при вызове раскрыть его в переменные

```
final def (int x, int y) = dva(2)
println x
println y

def dva (U) { X = U + 1; Y = U + 3; return [X, Y] }
```

https://ideone.com/T5T9uT

​

Comment: def dva (U) { X = U + 2; Y = U + 5; [X, Y] }

def (int x, int y) = dva(3)

print "x = "; println x
print "y = "; println y

Answer (score 1):

```
def dva (U) { X = U + 2; Y = U + 5; [X, Y] }

def (int x, int y) = dva(3)

print "x = "; println x
print "y = "; println y
```

Без `return` и `final` тоже работает (проверенно в NetBeans)

Compiling 1 source file to C:\Groovy\GroovyJavaDemo\build\classes

compile-single:

run-single:

x = 5

y = 8

ПОСТРОЕНИЕ УСПЕШНО ЗАВЕРШЕНО (общее время: 4 секунд)

Да, и без `int` тоже.

Окончательно:

```
def (x, y) = dva(3)
```